# Show mdTooltip until clicked, hide when clicked again

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to disable the mouse-hover effect and trigger mdTooltip on click and disable it on clicking again. Is it possible to do that? I thought the .toogle() method would be the right tool for that unfortunately it works the opposite way.

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
   <span matTooltip="Tooltip!" #tooltip="matTooltip" (click)="tooltip.toggle()">Test</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: I have heard that this feature was added  [link](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/3578/commits) but, I don't understand how I can make it work.

Comment: The material2 tooltips use this syntax: <span matTooltip="Tooltip!">I have a tooltip</span>

Comment: Did this work at one time or never?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, A better solution is using `matTooltipDisabled`

set it as `false` right before you call show and set it as `true` when you call hide

So you don't trigger extra change detection because of listening mouse events. (In this case, we can save 2, mouseenter and mouseleave )

Answer (score 26):

You should try using `event.stopImmediatePropagation();`

```
<span matTooltip="Tooltip!" 
  (mouseenter)="$event.stopImmediatePropagation()" 
  (mouseleave)="$event.stopImmediatePropagation()"
  #tooltip="matTooltip" (click)="tooltip.toggle()">Test</span>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZWdnZn3BgFpTOESHFcCk?p=preview)**

Comment: Great solution, too bad the material team didn't just give us a show-on-click option

Comment: I think I just figured out a better solution