# How to click CSS text-overflow ellipsis to display a long text in pop up?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a long sentence in table cell. So I use text-overflow to show ellipsis. My question is how to click the dots(...) to show the entire text in a popup?

```
  table {
      width: 100%;
      table-layout: fixed;
  }
  table td {
      border: 1px solid red;
      padding: 5px;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
```

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a1ffmf?file=src/app/table-basic-example.css)

Comment: In your example, you're already importing `MatTooltipModule`, why not use it?

Comment: I wonder not using tooltip but using popup. Tooltip is for hover, but I want to use click. Of course if there is no way to do then I would consider tooltip.

Comment: You can disable `MatTooltip`'s default event bind behavior and bind it to a click instead. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46613621/3367818

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When click toggle class `show`.

And add this code to css.

```
table td.show{
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: break-spaces;
  overflow: unset;
}
```

Please confirm this url.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a1ffmf-4chzaw?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.css