# Make matTooltip to appear by clicking the button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to add a tooltip to my button that should appear only if I click this button.
I looked at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602216/show-mdtooltip-until-clicked-hide-when-clicked-again) but it doesn't work for me for some reason.

The way it works for me now - the tooltip appears when I hover over the element. I want the tooltip to appear only after I click my element.

This is my code:

```
<div class="copy-link">
      <a
        class="padded ch-primary-alt-color ch-hoverable-link"
        target="_blank"
        aria-label="Copy link to the event to clipboard"
        tabindex=0
        matTooltip="Copied to clipboard"
        #tooltip="matTooltip"
        matTooltipPosition="above"
        (click)="tooltip.show()"
        [cdkCopyToClipboard]="shareLink"
      >
      <span class="share-link" tabindex=0 aria-label="Share the link">
        <i
          class="fa fa-link"
          aria-hidden="true"
        >
        </i>
      </span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Could you advise the solution for this, please?

Comment: Did you try entering the mouse enter and leave events from that example? Seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by disabling your tooltip and on click you run a method in component that enables it, runs the show() method and disables it again after some delay:

html template

```
<button
  [matTooltipDisabled]="true"
  #myTooltip="matTooltip" 
  matTooltip="Action done!"
  (click)="displayTooltip()">
</button>
```

component.Ts

```
...
@ViewChild("myTooltip") myTooltip: MatTooltip
...
public displayTooltip(){
  this.myTooltip.disabled = false;
  this.myTooltip.show()
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.myTooltip.disabled = true;
  }, 1000);

  [... other actions ...]
}
```

I used this in a reusable component which is just a button that copies to the clipboard the given value (generaly the label next to it), so the click displays the tooltip "copied !" when clicked, it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

I have a working example here, just adding the events from the solution you mentioned

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzdmf8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-overview-example.html

```
<a class="padded ch-primary-alt-color ch-hoverable-link" target="_blank"
    aria-label="Copy link to the event to clipboard" tabindex=0 matTooltip="Copied to clipboard" #tooltip="matTooltip"
    matTooltipPosition="above" 
    (mouseenter)="$event.stopImmediatePropagation()"
    (mouseleave)="$event.stopImmediatePropagation()" 
    (click)="tooltip.show()" 
    [cdkCopyToClipboard]="shareLink">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the template. You can try this out.

```
     <a mat-button
          (click)="tooltip.show()"
         #tooltip="matTooltip"
        [matTooltipDisabled]="true"
        matTooltip="Copied to clipboard"
        matTooltipPosition="above"
    show
  </a>
```